# How to move nav items around navbar in Bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

so I would like to move nav items closer to the center of my navbar with Bootstrap but am having trouble. I don't want them all the way to the outside but also not all the way to the center. For instance I would like the left elements to be center left and the right to be center right. I have included a picture and my code. Is there anyway to do this Bootstrap? Already tried offset and it messes up the nav elements.

[Picture](https://i.gyazo.com/c015f7bfb4b3c30b729576da80015173.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top" id="navbar">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="navbar-brand active" href="/"><img src="../static/img/123.png"></a>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Why Our Site<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#test">How it works</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="support">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="signup" class="btn btn-md btn-primary shadow-lg" role="button"><span>Sign up</span></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers) class. For example:

```
<nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top" id="navbar">
```

or check the grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: Perfect thank you! I used a container like so <ul class="container my-custom-container navbar-nav">. Custom container to restrict the width, but putting it all in a container worked. Thank you